# How to load bower dependencies from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bower

I created a new ASP.Net Core project using the "mvc" template. It already includes a bower.js file with some dependencies. However, when I change the bower.js file and add new dependencies, how can I load them?

I'm using Visual Studio Code and installed the "Bower package watcher" extension but it seems not to recognize the change.

Comment: Do you have bower installed? And is the file with your dependencies called bower.json?

Comment: It was in fact a bower installation issue. At first I didn't have it installed and then I forgot the -g option to install it globally. With bower properly installed it works. If you post an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: still the same. the change in json is not recognized. i do not know what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bower package watcher requires that bower be installed globally. You can test this by opening Terminal in VS Code (Ctrl + `) and typing in `bower`. If you get an unknown command error, install bower globally and try again.

You can install bower with npm by running `npm install -g bower` right from the Terminal you just opened in VS Code. Or, visit https://bower.io/ for other ways to install.

Comment: If you find out you don't have `npm`, the following may be helpful (on `Mint Linux` or `Ubuntu`): https://www.larshaendler.com/2016/07/06/install-npm-bower-and-grunt-on-linux-mint-17-mini-tutorial/